# AttributeError: SQLContext instance has no attribute 'createDataFrame'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am new in apache spark an try to work on the big query, when ever i try to run the code i have shared below it gives me error

> File "/****/***/spark-1.1.0/examples/src/main/python/testSql.py", line 25, in 
>       schemaEvents = sqlContext.createDataFrame(events)
>   AttributeError: SQLContext instance has no attribute 'createDataFrame'

I am following follwing links for the practice.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframes

code is shared below.

```
from pyspark.sql import *


from pyspark import *
#File = "/home/shafee/spark-1.1.0/results-20160315-075804.csv"  # Should be some file on your system
File = ""  # Should be some file on your system
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
Line = sc.textFile("results-20160315-075804.csv")
parts = Line.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
events = parts.map(lambda p: Row(Actor1Name=p[6], SourceUrl=int(p[56])))

schemaEvents = sqlContext.createDataFrame(events)

schemaPeople.registerTempTable("events")
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM ").collect()
worldcount = df.count()
print("Totel words counts in csv file: %i" % (worldcount))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Spark 1.1 and [`SQLContext.createDataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) has been introduced in Spark 1.3. You should update Spark version if you want to use follow the current programming guide.